# How to solve this error TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'currentUser.filteredFeed')

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to get the data from firebase through redux. But when I try to get currentUser.Filter its throwing me an error saying null is not an object (evaluating 'currentUser.filteredFeed')  but in firebase storage is is not null and it has some data. This is the code:

```
    function Feed(props) {
        const {currentUser } = props;
        const FilterFeed = currentUser.filteredFeed
        const [sq, setSq] = useState([])
      
        
        return (
            <View>
    
            </View>
     
        )
    }
    
    
    
    const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
        currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
    })
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Feed);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your connect function you are passing null as second argument. So that's why it is showing error.

Instead of null you can pass blank object like below:-

```
connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Feed)
```